# Independent Component Analysis as applied to a single time series

Tags: c++, math

First off I am not a financial engineering guru. I worked as a COBOL programmer for many years and although I am a bit rusty with c++ I can do alright after a bit of a refresher.

I have been trading futures for a few years now and have set myself the task of implementing ICA on a single stream of time series data (futures prices, stock prices).

The ICA algorithm comes as part of the it++ package (fastICA) however it is necessary to perform some preprocessing on the time series data as ica works on the premise that the number of observations is at least as large as the number of sources.

From what I have discovered the preprocessing involves constructing a matrix Y that contains the original time series in the 1st column, a lag-1 shifted version of the time series in the 2nd column etc.

```
eg.

Y= 1.0135518 - 0.7113242 - 0.3906069 1.565203
- 0.7113242 - 0.3906069 1.565203 0.0439317
- 0.3906069 1.565203 0.0439317 - 1.1656093
etc.
```

My questions are:

1. What steps are necessary to recover the independent sources in the time series data after ICA is performed?
2. How to order the IC's from most significant to least significant.

   If somebody could either answer these questions or point me in the direction of a suitable book or article I would be most gratefull. Preferably the book or article is more practicle in nature.

Comment: What do you mean by recovery?  If you are feeding the sources into the ICA, why not just keep a copy of them?  As for ordering, if this is simply based on values, why not use a built-in sort function for the matrix?

Comment: @Boris: I just re-formatted it; if the format is botched, I take responsibility, and will clean it up if you let me know what looks wrong (it seems ok to me)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Handbook of Blind Source Separation: Independent Component Analysis and Applications` by Pierre Comon and Christian Jutten as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ICA returns a separation matrix M. So to find your sources you need to multiply M by your matrix of original measurements. Ordering ICA components by their significance depends only on what you think is significant for you, e.g., variance or some other statistical property. ICA by itself does not provide any natural ordering mechanism.